# sqlite inner join update - 3 tables

Tags: sqlite, join, updates, multiple-tables

I have 3 tables on SQLite and like to update table1 based on the values from table3.

On MySQL:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id_t2 
JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.id_t3 = t3.id 
SET t1.name = 0 WHERE t3.name = 0;
```

I know, that SQLite no support UPDATE-JOIN, but I don't know, what is good solution without JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find id of row you want to update without using table on which update will be run. You could find those id's from only two tables 'table2' and 'table3'. Simple subquery will help you:

```
UPDATE table1 SET name = 0 
WHERE id_t2 IN (
    SELECT t2.id FROM table2 t2 
    INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.id_t3 = t3.id 
    WHERE t3.name = 0
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I corrected my code, can you now look?

Comment: @Rajdon I've updated the answer. You if need additional explanation - let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t1 SET name = 0 
WHERE t1.id_t2 IN (SELECT t2.id FROM t2 
WHERE t2.id_t3 IN (SELECT t3.id FROM t3 WHERE t3.name = 0));
```